# How can I swipe a row from a TableView to another

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, tableview

I have in one ViewControl two TableViews implemented. Initially one has data and another doesn't.

So, I was wondering how would I implement the gesture event of touching one row in the fulfilled TableView and swipe it to the empty TableView, in order to move that datum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the swipe gesture to each cell of your table, this gesture call a **Custom method** where you pass the `indexPath` of the cell then in your **Custom method** write a code for add this object from the array of first table to the second and remove it from first array. Finally you refresh boh table with `reloadData` method

Comment: Mirko, I did'nt implemented a specific class for the cells of my tableView. Do I have to do this first? If I only create a UISwipeGestureRecognizer defining the initWithTarget as my tableView won't work?

Answer (score 0):

What I've done so far... (It's slightly different of what @Mirko told)

1. Added the UISwipeGesture to the table (inside ViewDidLoad method), and defined it to capture the "Swipe Up" event, calling my event handler.

   ```
   swipeCell = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeUpEvent:)];
   swipeCell.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
   [self.tableA addGestureRecognizer:swipeCell];
   ```
2. Implemented the event handler, that get the cell selected by the swipe movement when it starts.

   ```
   -(IBAction)swipeUpEvent:(UIGestureRecognizer *) sender
   {

   CGPoint location = [sender locationInView:self.tableA];
   NSIndexPath *swipedIndexPath = [self.tableA indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];

   NSString *temp = [arrayA objectAtIndex:swipedIndexPath.row];

   [arrayB addObject:temp];
   [arrayA removeObjectAtIndex:swipedIndexPath.row];

   [self.tableB reloadData];
   [self.tableA reloadData];
   }
   ```

It may not be the most elegant solution for the problem, but at least I avoided creating an ActionListener for each cell. I hope it saves me some memory.